# How to Change Windows 7 OS HDD Display Name'?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, rename

The display name of my OS drive in Windows 7 (64 Ultimate) won't display as the name I've renamed it via properties, Diskpart and manually. What is going on!

As you can see in *My Computer* it is named `Drive g` even though Disk Manager knows it is `OS`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being named by a hidden file `autorun.inf`.

First, you'll need to view the hidden file by selecting the option in **Control Panel - Folder Options - View tab - Hidden files and folders - Show hidden files, folders, and drives**.

Next, navigate to My Computer - *drive you want to rename* and find `autorun.inf`

[image]

Now, just delete the `autorun.inf` file and voila!

[image]

Comment: The more interesting question IMO is, **why/how** did it happen?

Comment: @nitro2k01 I think it happened when I was swapping the storage HDDs, I accidentally swapped the OS disk (because I didn't remember in what order they were physically) and for some reason, it decided `Drive g` was appropriate when I reconnected it.

Comment: Doesn't worked for me. Is this method only for windows 7 64-bit or can be used on windows 8 32-bit as I renamed the drives and they changed right away. Also I can't see any file named "autorun.inf".

Comment: @Hunter you need to show hidden files to see it.

Comment: @Raystafarian Did it and also unchecked the hide unprotected system files thing to make sure if the autorun.inf file was system protected. But didn't see it.

Comment: @Hunter Oh I missed it when you said you're on Windows 8, I'm not sure about the differences for W8 vs W7 and I don't have W8 to test.